# Print 10 largest numeric array values in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Whenever someone adds an 'item' on my website, I log the item number in a file called items_added.log. I want to make a script which shows me the 5 most commonly added items. Let's say this is my array:

```
1 => 100
2 => 200
3 => 300
4 => 400
5 => 500
6 => 600
7 => 700
8 => 800
9 => 900
10 => 1000
```

In this case, I would want to print this array;

```
10 => 1000
9 => 900
8 => 800
7 => 700
6 => 600
5 => 500
```

How can I do so? Here's my code so far:

```
<?php
     $file     = 'items_added.log';
     $content  = file_get_contents($file);
     $arrItems = explode("\n", $content);
     function array_count_values_of($value, $array) {
        $counts = array_count_values($array);
        return $counts[$value];
     }
     $itemCounts   = array();
     foreach($arrItems as $item) {
        $itemCounts[$item] = array_count_values_of($item, $arrItems);
     }
     // Somehow print the 5 largest values (the 5 most commonly added items)
     // $itemCounts is an array which contains all items ever added & how many times they have been added
     // The structure is ItemNumber => Frequency
?>
```

Comment: why you use foreach+function instead of simple use `$itemCounts = array_count_values($arrItems);` ?

Comment: I'm counting the instances of a certain value in the array, not counting the amount of values in the array.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't see difference. Can you explain by example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [arsort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.krsort.php) and [array_splice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php).

No need to use any custom code.

```
<?php
$arr = [
  1  => 100,
  2  => 200,
  3  => 300,
  4  => 400,
  5  => 500,
  6  => 600,
  7  => 700,
  8  => 800,
  9  => 900,
  10 => 1000
];
arsort($arr);
$arr = array_slice($arr, 0, 5, 1);
print_r($arr);
?>
```

Hope that helps. Please let me know in case of further issues.

Comment: @James let me know in case of any issues, I have edited the answer and posted quick code also.

Comment: He should use arsort, because the values (100,200,300) are the frequencies, and he wants to sort by frequency.

Comment: Very true. Edited. Thanks, I was in a bit hurry .. :)

Comment: It's not showing me the original `$itemCount` keys, instead it's giving me its place in the array (if that makes any sense). Here's what I get (with my 'custom code'): `Array ( [0] => 7 [1] => 7 [2] => 6 [3] => 5 [4] => 3 )` - it's saying 0 instead of 413 which is the item which was added 7 times.

Comment: @James I have edited my answer: `$arr = array_slice($arr, 0, 5, 1);`. It should work now.

Answer (score 1):

You should use arsort, this sorts the array on the value (but in reverse, so from highest to lowest).

```
arsort($itemCounts);
$top5 = array_slice($itemCounts, 0, 5);
```

Then you have the $top5 of your array in the variable $top5.

Comment: I'm getting `Warning: array_slice() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given in /home/content/91/11630891/html/mash/ext/newap/ia/get_popular_items.php on line 23
NULL` - Something wrong with the code in my OP, perhaps?

Comment: Line 23 is `$top5       = array_slice($itemCounts, 0, 5);`

Comment: You could also vote for PHP Weblineindia's answer, that one will also work.

Comment: no need to assign `itemCounts` on `arsort($itemCounts);`. should use `arsort($itemCounts);` alone

Comment: @JeroendeJong You are already there but arsort will return either TRUE or FALSE. So you can not use that variable in `array_slice`. @James try this please: `arsort($itemCounts); print_r(array_splice($itemCounts, 5));`

Comment: Thanks PHP Weblineindia, I edited my answer to fix this problem!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$arr = [
        1  => 100,
        2  => 200,
        3  => 300,
        4  => 400,
        5  => 500,
        6  => 600,
        7  => 700,
        8  => 800,
        9  => 900,
        10 => 1000
    ];
    rsort($arr);
    print_r($arr);
?>
```